# I have a 'No overload for svc_methodNameCompleted matches delegate System.EventHandler...' Error and I dont know how to fix it?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database

Hi my method in my service reference is.

```
    public List<Lecture> ViewUsersLectures(string userID)
    {
        using (var context = new SE_App_DatabaseEntities())
        {
            // select query (linq style) to select all lectures from lectures table in database
            var results = from r in context.Lectures
                          where r.UserID == userID
                          select r;
            // return results to list which will we bind to a listbox in our mobile app
            return results.ToList();
        }
    }
```

So I use this but I have an error in the eventhandler line any help please?

```
        Service1Client svc = new Service1Client();
        svc.ViewUsersLecturesCompleted += new EventHandler<ViewUsersLecturesCompletedEventArgs>(svc_ViewUsersLecturesCompleted);
        svc.ViewUsersLecturesAsync(userID);
```

and my completed method is below

```
    void svc_ViewUsersLecturesCompleted(object sender, ViewLecturesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            // bind profiles to listbox
            LecturesListBox.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            MessageBox.Show("Profiles downloaded!", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem viewing lectures", "Unsuccessful", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured:" + e.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that your Completed method's EventArgs type doesn't match (missing "Users")?

void svc_ViewUsersLecturesCompleted(object sender, View**Users**LecturesCompletedEventArgs e)

Comment: Thank you I don't know how I missed that I went over it so many times checking it.